# Why verdigris and not rust?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

My son asked me about the discoloration on our outside brass doorknob, and I told him that it was [verdigris](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verdigris), explaining that it was basically [rust](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rust?s=t) that formed on brass, bronze and copper.

I know what it is and its origin (Old French "vere grez" "green of Greece") but I had no answer when he asked why we don't just call it rust.

Any ideas? One of the definitions of rust is:

> any film or coating on metal caused by oxidation

so it would seem to be *a* correct term to use, but I have no idea why it is not used(at least in my experience) when referring to oxidation of copper.

Comment: Verdigris forms on brass, bronze or copper, rust is found on iron or steel.

Comment: @user110518 - I've never seen verdigris on a bra.

Comment: @HotLicks - put your bra outside and take the fabric off :)

Comment: Verdigris isn't copper *oxide* (which is black), it is copper *carbonate.* The most likely place to see patches of copper *oxide* is on copper pipes used in plumbing, after soldering joints with a gas torch.

Comment: Why is a male deer a *stag* but a male elephant a *bull*? One of the definitions of *bull* is *an adult male of certain large mammals*, and deer are relatively large mammals, it would seem to be *a* correct term to use.

Comment: Verdigris forms on bronze statues.

Comment: @choster - Bull!!

Comment: Also, the only other common metal I can think off offhand that forms a similar coating when exposed to air is silver, and that black coating (actually a sulfide) is called "tarnish".  (Though if you want to get technical, other metals tarnish too - including copper, when a bright freshly-ecposed copper surface becomes dull, but doesn't form green verdigris.

Comment: @HotLicks Bet you Lady Liberty's got some...under her robes, of course. On the other hand, as Venkman said in the second film, she *is* French, so one never knows (about the bra, that is).

Comment: Are you asking 'why is a different word used when it is really rust?' ? If so, the answer is 'that's language' because there are different words for all sorts of similar things. Why is paste called paste when it's really dough (it's just flour and water and salt)? Birds are dinosaurs, why don't we  say there's a dinosaur singing out my window? Why is it prevaricating when it's just lying? The stuff on copper looks and feels different than the stuff on iron, I think that's enough reason to call them different.

Comment: What are you asking, please?

When you asked your favourite dictionaries or thesauruses, what did they say about this, please?

Answer (score 14):

Verdigris and Rust are both oxidation, but it depends on the metal which is oxidizing. (as [user110518](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/159691/user110518) stated)

verde = (latin) green

gris = (latin) grey (also at black) [ty @all]

rust = (old english) red

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/griseus

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verdigris

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rust

Comment: from the link you provided: " a comparable coating produced _on a metal other than iron_ by corrosion".  This suggests that copper oxide can be considered "rust" unless "comparable" necessarily  includes color

Comment: yea i think verdigris rust is like square rectangle...

Comment: Copper oxide is black, but that fact is is irrelevant, because the green color on copper exposed to moist air is mostly copper *carbonate.*

Comment: im no chemist, but looks pretty green to me @alephzero : https://www.google.com/search?q=oxidized+copper&safe=off&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVkNeZnZ3cAhUQSN8KHU_TCGYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=2400&bih=1184

Comment: google images (and/or the people who label / tag images of copper exposed to air) are not chemists either.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_oxide has a picture: it's a black solid or powder.  I had always assumed that the green patina that forms on copper was oxide, and would have made the same mistake until a minute ago when I read @alephzero's comment!  (Wikipedia says it's used as a pigment in ceramics "to produce blue, red, and green, and sometimes gray, pink, or black glazes."  IDK how that works, though.  (Also, Copper(I) oxide is red.)

Comment: Related: http://www.tech-faq.com/what-causes-copper-to-turn-green.html

Comment: @PeterCordes yea i thought so too about google. but EVERY picture is that same turquisy, verdigris hue?

Comment: @tidbertum: That's what happens when copper is exposed to air, rather than pure oxygen.  Copper oxide does form, but then it reacts with CO2 + H2O in the air, or with sulfur compounds.  See the "Reactions" section in https://sciencestruck.com/why-does-copper-oxidize-turn-green.  So the process does start with oxidation, but it's really a redox reaction, with multiple possible endpoints that have similar green colours.

Comment: lol omg i just realized i forgot half the latin . editing answer :)

Answer (score 7):

The definitions linked from the question highlight three main differences between rust and vertigris:

- the metal: [iron](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rust?s=t) vs [copper, brass, or bronze](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verdigris)
- the color: [red or orange](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rust?s=t) vs [green or bluish](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verdigris)
- the composition of the coating: [chiefly of ferric hydroxide and ferric **oxide**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rust?s=t) vs [principally of basic copper **sulfate**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verdigris)

Comment: Sorry about the cross-post.

Comment: @PhilSweet by 'cross-post' do you mean posting the same answer at the same time? No problem, but I wouldn't consider your answer a cross-post anyway because it had different info than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Others have already mentioned that verdigris is not caused by an oxidative process.  So that is answer enough.  But to go further, even if verdigris *were* caused by an oxidative process:

- According to my Merriam-Webster dictionary (10th ed) the word *verdigris* has its origins in the 14th century, well before chemical principles of oxidation were understood.  So why wasn't verdigris called rust?  Because the deposits look entirely different and no one considered them as chemically similar processes.
- Today, it would be misleading (at best) to call verdigris "rust" because rust also carries the connotation of a rust (brownish-red) color.
- Rust is a *sub-type* of oxidation.  Not all oxidation is rust.  The term rust is reserved for oxidation of iron-based alloys.  Even if the uncited definition in the question comes from a reliable source, and might be technically correct (or jargony) *in certain contexts*, I doubt that context would extend to everyday descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

Vert-de-gris would have had a special name because it was of commercial importance. Rust, less so.

In modern technical usage, the term refers to Copper(II) acetate monohydrate ("neutral verdigris") or Basic copper (II) acetate ("blue verdigris" or "green verdigris").

A 19th century (the 3rd French edition published in 1892) book (*[Traité de chimie industrielle](https://books.google.com/books?id=8q05AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA617&dq=%22vert-de-gris%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv1qeM0J3cAhVBSq0KHXZ0B7EQ6AEINDAB#v=onepage&q=%22vert-de-gris%22&f=false)* by Johann Rudolf von Wagner) gives some uses that were in use at the time: pigment for oil paints and water color; to make Paris green, for dyeing cloth, and in gelding bronze (specifically, for giving a reddish finish to fire-gelded bronze).

Even at the time of writing, the author notes "verdigris is used much less often than previously, as it has been replaced by copper sulfate in many of its applications."

Going further back, the same substance is listed as a drug in Dioscorides' *[Materia Medica](http://www.cancerlynx.com/BOOKFIVEWINES.PDF)* (1st century AD). The author notes that it's produced in Cyprus, which had mining industry in antiquity. The word "copper" itself comes from the place.

Answer (score 1):

Verdigris isn't rust because it isn't a product of oxidation. It is a different chemical reaction. The natural stuff is either copper carbonate hydroxide, or dicopper cloride trihydroxide. The artist's pigment is copper acetate.

Comment: While this is true, I don't think it's any explanation for having two different terms, considering they long predate modern chemistry.

Comment: @choster  We have a habit of retrofitting old terms to our brave new world's understanding. Your car's dashboard no longer stops you from getting splashed by mud from horses' hooves.

Comment: @PhilSweet and my glove box doesn't contain any gloves

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't think that was his point.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not rust is also applicable to verdigris... why shouldn't it have another name? It's like asking why we call crabapples crabapples and not apples... they might be apples but why can't they have its own specific name?